# Approximation of arcsin in C

Tags: c, algorithm, precision, trigonometry, taylor-series

I've got a program that calculates the approximation of an arcsin value based on Taylor's series.

[image: arcsin]

My friend and I have come up with an algorithm which has been able to return the almost "right" values, but I don't think we've done it very crisply. Take a look:

```
double my_asin(double x)
{
    double a = 0;
    int i = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    a = x;
    for(i = 1; i < 23500; i++)
    {
        sum += a;
        a = next(a, x, i);
    }
}

double next(double a, double x, int i)
{
    return a*((my_pow(2*i-1, 2)) / ((2*i)*(2*i+1)*my_pow(x, 2)));
}
```

I checked if my_pow works correctly so there's no need for me to post it here as well. Basically I want the loop to end once the difference between the current and next term is more or equal to my EPSILON (0.00001), which is the precision I'm using when calculating a square root.

---

This is how I would like it to work:

```
while(my_abs(prev_term - next_term) >= EPSILON)
```

But the function *double next* is dependent on **i**, so I guess I'd have to increment it in the while statement too. Any ideas how I should go about doing this?

---

Example output for -1:

```
$ -1.5675516116e+00
```

Instead of:

```
$ -1.5707963268e+00
```

---

Thanks so much guys.

Comment: I think I need the difference between the absolute value of the previous and the next term, rather than just comparing epsilon to a number. I'm gonna try it out.

Comment: Note that your first formula is wrong, all terms in the Taylor series of arcsin have a `+` sign.

Comment: @MartinR I don't think it's wrong.

Comment: @Foxxy, it is clearly wrong. How do you get 3rd term from it?

Comment: All terms have a + sign. It seems correct in your `next()` function, only the first screenshot of the formula is wrong.

Comment: @Foxxy: The order 5 term in the graphic image has a minus sign, whereas all the other terms have a positive sign.

Comment: I see what you mean, I'm sorry, I posted the wrong image. The right one is lower on the page.

Comment: @imre I just added an answer with my solution. Using Taylor for `arcsin` directly is not a good idea as the result is very inaccurate even for very big number of terms. Using `arctan` or any other identity is much more precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issues with your code and question include:

1. Your image file showing the Taylor series for arcsin has two errors: There is a minus sign on the *x*<sup>5</sup> term instead of a plus sign, and the power of *x* is shown as *x*<sup>*n*</sup> but should be *x*<sup>2*n*+1</sup>.
2. The *x* factor in the terms of the Taylor series for arcsin **increases** by *x*<sup>2</sup> in each term, but your formula `a*((my_pow(2*i-1, 2)) / ((2*i)*(2*i+1)*my_pow(x, 2)))` **divides** by *x*<sup>2</sup> in each term. This does not matter for the particular value -1 you ask about, but it will produce wrong results for other values, except 1.
3. You ask how to end the loop once the difference in terms is “more or equal to” your epsilon, but, for most values of *x*, you actually want less than (or, conversely, you want to **continue**, not **end**, while the difference is greater than or equal to, as you show in code).
4. The Taylor series is a poor way to evaluate functions because its error increases as you get farther from the point around which the series is centered. Most math library implementations of functions like this use a minimax series or something related to it.
5. Evaluating the series from low-order terms to high-order terms causes you to add larger values first, then smaller values later. Due to the nature of floating-point arithmetic, this means that accuracy from the smaller terms is lost, because it is “pushed out” of the width of the floating-point format by the larger values. This effect will limit how accurate any result can be.
6. Finally, to get directly to your question, the way you have structured the code, you directly update `a`, so you never have both the previous term and the next term at the same time. Instead, create another `double b` so that you have an object `b` for a previous term and an object `a` for the current term, as shown below.

Example:

```
double a = x, b, sum = a;
int i = 0;
do
{
    b = a;
    a = next(a, x, ++i);
    sum += a;
} while (abs(b-a) > threshold);
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your input. Your example helped me a lot and generates better results so far. However, I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean in point 2. Should I change the formula to increase by _x^2_? Currently, the output for asin(1) is `1.2416666667e+00` on treshold 0.00000000001...

Comment: @Foxxy: Point 2 merely points out that the image is incorrect. The code is not incorrect in the same regard. The value 1.2416666667e+00 is what you get for evaluating 3 terms (for i = 0, 1, and 2), so I expect that means your loop is terminating earlier than desired.

Comment: Ad #6: Unless I am mistaken, the terms of the series as not alternating. For positive x all terms are positive, and for negative x all terms are negative.

Comment: I edited the question to allow for the fact that the series is not alternating. (I may have been thrown off by the incorrect x**n in the image.) note that the resulting code is suitable for arcsine, but adjustments would be needed if this were used for alternating series.

Comment: @EricPostpischil asin(-1) now gives me `$ -1.5665686059e+00` on 17808 iterations. When I try to increase EPSILON more than `#define EPSILON2 0.00000000001`, the results are -nan.

Comment: @EricPostpischil also, asin(0.1 to 0.9) returns _inf_.

Answer (score 2):

using **Taylor series** for `arcsin` is extremly imprecise as the stuff converge very badly and there will be relatively big differencies to the real stuff for finite number of therms. Also using `pow` with integer exponents is not very precise and efficient.

However using `arctan` for this is OK

```
arcsin(x) = arctan(x/sqrt(1-(x*x)));
```

as its Taylor series converges OK on the `<0.0,0.8>` range all the other parts of the range can be computed through it (using trigonometric identities). So here my **C++** implementation (from my arithmetics template):

```cpp
T atan    (const T &x)                                              // = atan(x)
    {
    bool _shift=false;
    bool _invert=false;
    bool _negative=false;
    T z,dz,x1,x2,a,b; int i;
    x1=x; if (x1<0.0) { _negative=true; x1=-x1; }
    if (x1>1.0) { _invert=true; x1=1.0/x1; }
    if (x1>0.7) { _shift=true; b=::sqrt(3.0)/3.0; x1=(x1-b)/(1.0+(x1*b)); }
    x2=x1*x1;
    for (z=x1,a=x1,b=1,i=1;i<1000;i++)  // if x1>0.8 convergence is slow
        {
        a*=x2; b+=2; dz=a/b; z-=dz;
        a*=x2; b+=2; dz=a/b; z+=dz;
        if (::abs(dz)<zero) break;
        }
    if (_shift) z+=pi/6.0;
    if (_invert) z=0.5*pi-z;
    if (_negative) z=-z;
    return z;
    }
T asin    (const T &x)                                              // = asin(x)
    {
    if (x<=-1.0) return -0.5*pi;
    if (x>=+1.0) return +0.5*pi;
    return ::atan(x/::sqrt(1.0-(x*x)));
    }
```

Where `T` is any floating point type (`float,double`,...). As you can see you need `sqrt(x)`, `pi=3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105`, `zero=1e-20` and `+,-,*,/` operations implemented. The `zero` constant is the target precision.

So just replace `T` with `float/double` and ignore the `::` ...

Answer (score 1):

> so I guess I'd have to increment it in the while statement too

Yes, this might be a way. And what stops you?

```
int i=0;
while(condition){
   //do something
   i++;
}
```

Another way would be using the for condition:

```
for(i = 1; i < 23500 && my_abs(prev_term - next_term) >= EPSILON; i++)
```

Comment: I removed the condition for **i** because it was there really just to end the loop at some point. `for(i = 1; my_abs(sum - a) >= EPSILON; i++)` just gives me weird values, so I guess it's failing on the first term.

Comment: Wmy my_abs(sum - a)? I think this condition is wrong (tems become smaller and smaller, so this difference is increasing). Check your thinking again. Also you may want to use the condition @Nico Schertler suggested in question's comments.

Comment: `double prev_term = 1; double next_term = 0.5*(x / prev_term + prev_term);
  while(my_abs(prev_term - next_term) >= EPSILON)
  {
   prev_term = next_term;
   next_term = 0.5*(x / prev_term + prev_term);
  }
  return next_term;` This works perfectly for me in the square root calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is wrong. Here is the correct formula: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/taylor11.pdf.

P.S. also note that your formula and your series are not correspond to each other.

[image]

---

You can use while like this:

```
while( std::abs(sum_prev - sum) < 1e-15 )
    {
        sum_prev = sum;
        sum += a;
        a = next(a, x, i);
    }
```

Comment: @Foxxy, Does this solve your problem? Help at least?