# Approximating atan without a math library

Tags: c, trigonometry, pi, math.h

I've been googling around for a solution to this problem. I've seen a number of ways to calculate atan(theta) for any -1 <= theta <= 1, but I am not sure what to do when theta is bigger or smaller than those bounds.

I assume I need to add or subtract multiples of pi to offset it? Is this line of thinking correct?

Currently I have:

```
double my_atan(double x)
{
    return x - (x*x*x)/3 + (x*x*x*x*x)/5;
}
```

Which is using the [taylor series](http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf).

And for the following code,

```
int x;
for (x=0; x<M_PI*2; x++)
{
    printf("Actual: %f\n",    atan(x));
    printf("Approx: %f\n", my_atan(x));
    printf("\n");
}
```

It quickly loses control (as expected, as it's out of range):

```
Actual: 0.000000
Approx: 0.000000

Actual: 0.785398
Approx: 0.866667

Actual: 1.107149
Approx: 5.733333

Actual: 1.249046
Approx: 42.600000

Actual: 1.325818
Approx: 187.466667

Actual: 1.373401
Approx: 588.333333

Actual: 1.405648
Approx: 1489.200000
```

Not pictured here, but the output is fairly accurate when theta is within the appropriate range.

So my question is what steps exactly need to be taken to the my_tan function to allow it to support wider bounds?

Been staring at this for a while and so any guidance that can be offered would be much appreciated

Comment: Lookup CORDIC for an efficient algorithm or implement the Taylor series as outline on the corresponding Wikipedia article (it only terminates for |x| < 1 so you need to scale the argument appropriately).

Comment: Taylor is bad for this due to poor convergence rate and convergence radius. There are better techniques: best discovered by searching, but a Newton Raphson I believe works well.

Comment: keyword: cordic atan   http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF5430/v12/undervisningsmateriale/dirk/Lecture_cordic.pdf

Comment: For a single-precision implementation, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692859/best-machine-optimized-polynomial-minimax-approximation-to-arctangent-on-1-1)

Comment: the domain of arctan function is not the angles, its (-inf,inf). Get used to use the syntax 'atan(x) = theta'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me complete your example and talk about some things that might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


double my_atan(double x)
{
    return x - (x*x*x)/3 + (x*x*x*x*x)/5 - (x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/7;
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    for (x=0.0; x<M_PI*2; x+=0.1)
    {
        printf("x: %f\n",    x);
        printf("Actual: %f\n",    atan(x));
        printf("Approx: %f\n", my_atan(x));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The term `int x` is an integer and you are approximating large angles. try to use doubles here you get no conversioncast errors.

Now to your problem. The Taylor series you use only works if your |x| < 1.

Taylor Series get inaccurate the more you get away from a given point or in your case zero (0+x).

That series works well up to `pi/4`, even at that point it is very inaccurate but larger values get very bad. So for smaller angles it works well enough.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a 7 instead of 5?

Answer (score 3):

The solution I used for a fixed point library was a minimax approximation using the [Remez algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remez_algorithm). Even there, I used a different set of coefficients for three ranges: 0 to 0.5; 0.5 to 0.75, and 0.75 to 1. With that breakdown I was able to get 1 ULP accuracy.

Then you need good argument reduction to get the argument in range. In my case I used a good reciprocal function for arguments over 1. Here are the identities:

```
atan(-x) == -atan(x)

atan(x) == pi/2 - atan(1/x) // for x > 1
```

There is a [nice blog post](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/21/better-function-approximations) on Taylor vs. Remez approximations [here](http://lolengine.net/blog/2011/12/21/better-function-approximations); at that site is also a [Remez toolkit](http://lolengine.net/wiki/oss/lolremez) for finding the coefficients you need.

Comment: Good thoughts about the issues +1.  Not impressed with the blog post as it centers on absolute error over the interval and not relative error which is akin to `ULP` measurement.

Comment: @chux, about halfway through the lolremez toolkit tutorial there is a "switch to relative error" http://lolengine.net/wiki/doc/maths/remez/tutorial-relative-error

Comment: @DougCurrie still missing one identity to maintain performance and accuracy as if `x>0.8` the Taylor series approach starts to converge more and more badly (the closer it gets to `1`). I am using `atan(x)-atan(y)=atan((x-y)/(1+x.y))`  see [my C++ atan,asin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50894477/2521214)